# SES metrics not updated in cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-java-2.0

We have configured tracking in cloudwatch for sending emails via AWS SES programmatically via AWS SDK ( as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-java.html)). Whenever I send an email for the first time with a new configuration set I am able to see the metrics (open, click) value updated to 1. When I send the same email to another recipient the metric value should increase to 2 but there is no change in the cloudwatch metric and it always shows value as 1.

I have configured message tags and configuration set as well.

I checked after few hours but still, metrics were not updated. I am not sure if there is some issue with cloudwatch - SES configuration or I am missing any configuration in the graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check in the cloudwatch graphed metrics. You may have selected Statistic value to Average which is default selection. You can try after changing that value to Sum. [View Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI8X9.png)

Comment: A thousand times this.    The default for the CloudWatch graph is a confusing line that is stuck at "1".